# Need simple sample program for core data in iPhone

Tags: iphone, core-data, sqlite, sample

Could please share a simple program(or link) to understand core data in iPhone. The program should cover add & delete a entry in table view. Program without IB is preferable.

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read the blog on CoreData from apple

[Building a Sample Core Data Application](http://developer.apple.com/cocoa/coredatatutorial/index.html)

Read more

[Cocoa Dev Central . Articles . Build a Core Data App](http://cocoadevcentral.com/articles/000085.php)

[iPhone Core Data: Your First Steps](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/iphone-core-data/)

[Core Data Tutorial: Getting Started](http://www.raywenderlich.com/934/core-data-tutorial-getting-started)

Answer (score 0):

Have you read through the core data programming guide on the Apple Developer center? [link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/iPhoneCoreData01/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008305)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the Stanford iPhone development course, in particular lecture 12
http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs193p/cgi-bin/drupal/downloads-2010-fall

Apple also have a lot of sample code in the developer program, including an excellent introduction to core data http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/iPhoneCoreData01/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008305

Answer (score 0):

1. Open Xcode
2. File -> New Project
3. iOS or Mac App, you choose
4. Select the App Type (Master-Detail, etc) again, you choose
5. Choose Next
6. Give it a name, company identifier
7. Check the box next to "Use CoreData"
8. Choose Next
9. Find a home on the file system for your new app (~/Documents will work just fine)
10. Choose Create
11. Open [Your App Name]AppDelegate.m and notice that Xcode wrote all the coredata scaffolding for you!

Answer (score 0):

I was also looking for simple example regarding this but unfortunately could not found which tells me straight forward. Here is what I have prepared. It is very basic example iOS project, shows only save and retrieve data in SQLite using pure Core Data framework.
http://www.iosmobileapps.biz/examples/CoreDataEx.zip 
Hope you will find this useful.